# Context lost when exception propagates to DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer using Spring Boot Sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a spring boot application, which uses spring for Kafka and Sleuth.

I have a kafka listener and configured it with DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.

The span and trace works inside the logic of the listener. However in case an exception is propagates and is caught by DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer the span and trace is not available there.

I assume it is because the tracing is wrapped around the listener, while the DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer is executed after the wrapped logic has erased the context.

Has anyone been able to solve this issue and has a solution to this?

My setup looks as follows:

Configuration bean:

```
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerRecordRecoverer consumerRecordRecoverer(final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        return new MyDeadLetterPublishRecoverer(kafkaTemplate);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonErrorHandler commonErrorHandler(final ConsumerRecordRecoverer consumerRecordRecoverer) {
        return new DefaultErrorHandler(consumerRecordRecoverer, new FixedBackOff(100, 1));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            CommonErrorHandler commonErrorHandler) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(commonErrorHandler);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer:

```
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDeadLetterPublishRecoverer.class);

    public MyDeadLetterPublishRecoverer(final KafkaOperations<?, ?> template) {
        super(template);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, @Nullable Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Exception exception) {
        String spanId = MDC.get("spanId");
        String traceId = MDC.get("traceId");
        logger.info("traceId: {} spanId: {} from deadletter recoverer", traceId, spanId);
        super.accept(record, consumer, exception);
    }

}
```

Listener

```
@Service
public class MyListener {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyListener.class);

    @KafkaListener(id = "MY_ID", topics = "MY-LISTENER", groupId = "my-group")
    public void consume(final ConsumerRecord<String, String> data) {

        String spanId = MDC.get("spanId");
        String traceId = MDC.get("traceId");
        logger.info("traceId: {} spanId: {} from listener", traceId, spanId);

        logger.info("Hello world!!!");
        throw new RuntimeException("bang");
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.0")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The output is as follows when a message is received:

```
2022-01-07 15:59:36.934  INFO [,71df84ca082d7fd0,72a0e0a2a2e58bd1] 105886 --- [    MY_ID-0-C-1] com.example.demo.MyListener              : traceId: 71df84ca082d7fd0 spanId: 72a0e0a2a2e58bd1 from listener
2022-01-07 15:59:36.934  INFO [,71df84ca082d7fd0,72a0e0a2a2e58bd1] 105886 --- [    MY_ID-0-C-1] com.example.demo.MyListener              : Hello world!!!
2022-01-07 15:59:36.934  INFO [,,] 105886 --- [    MY_ID-0-C-1] c.e.d.k.MyDeadLetterPublishRecoverer     : traceId: null spanId: null from deadletter recoverer
```

I thought about two possibilities:

1. One is to add span and trace id to the exception manually, which seems quite cumbersome
2. The alternative is to have wrapper a between the sleuth wrapper and the actual listener, which keeps span and trace id and in case that an exception is thrown the wrapper rethrows another exception with span and trace id.

But none of them seems very appealing.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a known issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1704